# Fetching all Cordova plugins used in the project

Tags: javascript, cordova, go

I recently had to build legacy code in cordova and they provided only www folder. Is there a way to add all the plugins used in the project like "go get" command in Go? It would be a lot easier to build the code if some tools were available.

Comment: I think if you've only got the www folder then you're stuck with having to manually go through the code and see what plugins it requires.

Comment: they should have provided the config.xml too, and have the plugins there

Comment: Well, I was unaware of node-webkit. Building was easy and I didn't have to worry about adding plugins. This could have been a great suggestion back then.